# Question on the definition of Lebesgue Integration - on the "codomain" of the integral operator..

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory

I am currently self-studying basic measure theory, and I cannot fully understand the definition of the Lebesgue integral.

My book says: (Here, $X$ is a measure space equipped with some sigma-algebra and a measure.)

> If $f: X \to [-\infty, \infty]$ is measurable, Then we define $\int f = \int f^+ - \int f^- $ whenever at least one of $\int f^+ $ or $\int f^-$ is finite. $f$ is called integrable if its integral exists as a finite number.

Then they give the following definition.

> If $f: X \to \bf C$ is measurable, then we define $\int f = \int \mathfrak {Re} f + i \int \mathfrak {Im}f $ whenever the real part and the imaginary part is both integrable.

But this definition seems to be incompatible with the former definition. Say for example, let $X$ be the real line with the Lebesgue measure, and let $f(x) = |x|$. Then when we view $f$ as a $[-\infty, \infty]$-valued function, its integral is $\infty$. However, if we view $f$ as a $\mathbf C$-valued function, its integral is undefined, since its real part ($|x|$) is not integrable.

I feel like:

> To be pedantic, there are two kinds of integrals, one is the $\overline{\bf R}:=[-\infty, \infty]$-valued integral, and another being the $\mathbf C$-valued integral. Therefore, strictly speaking, we should write $\int^{\overline{\bf R}} _X f$ or $\int ^ {\bf C} _X f $ to denote which kind of integral we are referring to.

Is my view correct, or incorrect?

(I think this may be a foolish question, but I am a beginner in measure theory.)

Comment: I observe in the complex definition that both real part and imaginary part must be "integrable," and I observe in the real definition that "integrable" requires a finite integral. So your example about $|x|$ does not apply.

Comment: You are right. The real-valued integral can always be written, no matter whether $f$ is integrable or not. The complex intergral by definition only exists if both real and imaginary part of $f$ are integrable.